# UISwitch in UITableViewCell id not visually disabled

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiswitch

I have an UITableView where all my cells have an UISwitch as an accessoryView.

I also have an array of all my UISwitches.

At the viewDidAppear method I iterate through my array of UISwitches and disable them.

It is all working fine.

The problem is when I move the UITableView up and down and the UISwitches that get hidden and shown again are not dimmed. They are disabled as intended but they look like they are enabled.

How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your cell are getting reused, and therefore the cell switches are getting reused. One solution, is to force your cells to not get reused ie:

```
    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

//if (cell == nil) {

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];

    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
            cell = (MyCustomCell *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }

//}
```

Notice that the if cell==nil is commented out, so the cells are never reused. Obviously not great for conserving memory and such, but if you don't have a large or weird tableview, you probably wouldn't even notice.

Another thing you could try is keep an array of boolean values that determine whether or not the switch should be checked, and use that array in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: @AndréCytryn: coder's second suggestion is better. Cell reusing is there for a reason. Try to handle this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: But what should I do with the array of booleans? Its not clear for me how it is going to help me with the switch not being dimmed

Comment: @AndréCytryn: array of booleans would correspond to indexes of cellviews - so you'd know in cellForRowAtIndexPath: if you need to enable or disable certain switch.

Comment: @rokjarc I want all switches disabled. I have a segmented control that keeps switches disabled when the selectedIndex is equal to zero, and enable when selected index is equal to one. This code is working fine.
I dont know if I am being clear. My problem is not about enabling or disabling them, its when I move the tableView, the switches that get off the screen comes back like they were visually enabled, but they are not. I'm going to post a pic here.

Comment: The first one shows when the table loads:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/815/firstg.png/
The second one shows whe I move the table up a bit and then move down a bit:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/3/secondy.png/
But the first switch is still disabled, which is right. Still, its not dimmed like the others, which is wrong.

Comment: @AndréCytryn: yes, those switches get enabled in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` when cells are being reused. You can solve this problem if you control enabling/disabling switches (also) in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. For this you need an ouside reference (for example array of booleans)